# Remove minimize and maximize window buttons in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

How can I remove the minimize and maximize buttons on a gtk# window, I came across 
[this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2004-December/msg00368.html), but wasn't very sure how to use it in gtk#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This GTK# thread](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Remove-Minimize-Maximize-Buttons-td4578289.html) discusses the given indirect method in Mono terms.

```
this.TypeHint = Gdk.WindowTypeHint.Dialog;
```

It uses value from [WindowTypeHint](http://docs.go-mono.com/) enumeration to set [Window.TypeHint](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3AGdk.Window.TypeHint) property to `WindowTypeHint.Dialog` value.

**P.S.:** I was unable to find any good references for GDK# documentation.

Comment: I also found WindowTypeHint.Dialog didn't work with Ubuntu Unity, but Gdk.WindowTypeHint.Utility did.

Comment: This doesn't work in Raspbian Jessie, either. I don't believe there is a way to remove the minimize button (Utility, Dialog hints both failed.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky way to remove the minimize button (this is tested on Raspbian Jessie)

Set the window type to `WindowTypeHint.Menu`

But, when the window starts it won't be focused, which isn't good. So, in the constructor of the dialog, after the `this.Build ();` line, add this: `this.Present ();` and it will focus the window.